# Weird situation on onClick(), if else condition is failing

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-button, onresume

I'm having a very weird situation in my app. I have an activity, on which I have log in button. On `button` click I'm checking whether user is logged in or not, and simultaneously showing proper message. My code looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (loginUserId == null || loginAccessToken == null) {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClassName("com.example.poc",
                "com.example.poc.LoginPromptDialog");
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Else condition here!");
    }
}
```

On else condition I'm printing on the `log`.

In my case take a scenario that user is not logged in, then `Login Prompt Activity` will be shown. I have a `skip` button on my `Second Activity`, on that button I'm just calling `finish()` method. And I'm coming back from `Second Activity` to `First Activity`. This is confirmed that my `onResume()` method is called when coming back from `Second Activtiy`.

Still user is not logged in and when I click again button on the `First Activity` my else condition is called. Why again my `if` condition is not called?

I can't figure out why this is happening.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try restart Eclipse and rebuild project?

Comment: Neither loginUserId or loginAccessToken are null. Check all the points where they might get initialized, your app is obviously passing to one (or several) of them.

Comment: check what values loginUserId and loginAccessToken have when you are in the Else. That should get you the problem.

Comment: @DigCamara It was the problem with my if statement because I was passing `loginUserId=""` inside my if, it solved my problem. Thanks. +1

Comment: @NickHol It was the problem with my if statement because I was passing `loginUserId=""` inside my if, it solved my problem. Thanks. +1

Comment: Good for you! Anyhow, add it as an answer and mark it as closed, that way it won't show up in the "unanswered" column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting `""` values from the other activity. Thanks to the comments I got. Solved.

Comment: you can use TextUtils.isEmpty(String) if you wish to handle both cases (empty or null).